# Difference between the red dot and holographic sight?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Obviously the two have different looks to them and the red dot is less chunky so you can see more of the area at once.

But is there any differences to them other than that? Do they affect the weapons stats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no statistical improvement by any of the scopes, they just give you further zeroing distance and allow you to shoot enemies at a further range with (relative) ease.

The only differences between RDS and HS is as you mentioned, **the size and shape of the physical sight as well as the reticle, and according to [this source](http://www.en.magicgameworld.com/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-weapon-attachments-guide/), the holographic zooms ever so slightly farther.**